# Trigger is deleted when drop and create the table, how to handle this in a process which requires to drop the table

Tags: sql-server, database-design, triggers

There is a process which has huge ETL process and finally it dumps the data in table X of Ddatabase ABC
I wanted to create a mirror of this table on table Y which is on Database DEF of different server.

I had created a trigger for this which would push the data on Insertion of the table.
But later came to know that the ETL process drops the table and re-creates it.
Which results in dropping of the trigger as well.

What way can I implement this process to make an exact copy of the table on another server DB.

Edit:

a) I don't have any control over the ETL process. Hence I can't do any modification to it and want to keep the process discrete.

 b) I cannot **truncate** table Y as DDL is not supported by linked servers, Hence I want to **delete** Table Y and then insert

Comment: Recreate the trigger after the table is created? That, however, could make your ETL very slow (as it'll load to your table, and keep firing the triggers). What do you want to happen on the other server while the ETL goes on? If the table is dropped on Server A, do you want it dropped on Server B? Would configuring a linked server not be easier on the other server?

Comment: Table shouldn't be deleted on the other server.
But instead, the trigger will delete all data from Table Y and insert all data existing in table X into it.

P.S : I dont want to make any changes to existing ETL process

Comment: Hi. Please clarify via post edits, not comments.

Comment: Sure...I will edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

> What way can I implement this process to make an exact copy of the
>   table on another server DB

The best way to it is to use [SQL Server Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-2017)

If for any reasons you prefer to recreate the trigger on the recreated table you can use [DDL Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-2017) that should create your trigger in the event of table creation.

P.S. Why don't you use `TRUNCATE` table (with index disabling if needed) instead of `drop`/`create`?

Comment: >>Why don't you use TRUNCATE table (with index disabling if needed) instead of drop/create?

You are correct. But I have no control over the ETL process else would have did that. Thanks!